# How to use labels in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file and I want to show the user the process in the file. I've created small tables with Operation and Status headers. Each table is for a particular command/line. After the line has run, I print the corresponding table, which clears the screen and prints the new table with the updated status. So you get a good look. This is the code:

```
@echo off

REM   Process started
goto zeroth
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
REM   do some work. first operation is done
goto first
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
REM   do some work. second operation is done
goto second
REM ...

:zeroth
cls
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Waiting
echo  * op2                                     Waiting
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
echo.

:first
cls
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Waiting
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
echo.

:second
cls
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Done
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
echo.

pause
```

but it doesn't work. I've checked other label examples and they usually have `goto end` or something at the end, but I'm not going to close the window. What should I be modifying?

Comment: Sometimes it might be a good idea just to remove `@echo off`, so you can see all actions done...

Comment: @aschipfl Where's the fun in that? :D

Comment: I read your question like you want to echo all the actions your script does...

Comment: Nope. There are like 3-4 actions which does only one thing, and I output it as one operation. Even though I output 4 operations in the table, there are many commands. If I were to output them all, it'd look messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of batch files as simply a list of CMD commands that the OS needs to run, and the order in which to run them in. Like other scripting languages, batch files are run from the top down, unless the direction is altered by `goto` statements and their corresponding line labels.

In your case, `goto zeroth` goes to the `:zeroth` label, and then continues on its merry way towards the bottom of the file. Because it never gets told to go higher up in the script, it never does.

Fortunately, you can also use labels in batch to simulate subroutines if you replace `goto` with `call`. (It's not really a subroutine; it's more like running a chunk of the script as its own separate batch script.) When you do this, you also have to use `goto :eof` to tell the script where the "subroutine" ends.

```
@echo off

REM   Process started
call :zeroth
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
REM   do some work. first operation is done
call :first
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
REM   do some work. second operation is done
call :second
REM ...
pause
REM We are at the end of the main chunk of code; everything below this is a subroutine
exit /b

:zeroth
cls
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Waiting
echo  * op2                                     Waiting
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
echo.
goto :eof

:first
cls
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Waiting
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
echo.
goto :eof

:second
cls
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Done
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
echo.
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

`goto` are pretty simple, the script is read from top to bottom and once down he does not go back unless to invite them. The `goto` command is a way to do that.

example:

```vb
@echo off

echo goto is also used to skip a step, example go directly to step-2.
@timeout /t 2 /nobreak>NUL
goto step-2

:step-1
echo hello world
@timeout /t 2 /nobreak>NUL
goto step-3

:step-2
echo How are you? Oh sorry, I missed Salute.
@timeout /t 2 /nobreak>NUL
goto step-1

:step-3
echo Show me your code
@timeout /t 2 /nobreak>NUL
type %~f0 | more

exit /b 0
```

Edit:
Same example modified with `call` to show you the script continue from where was called with the help of `goto :eof`

```vb
@echo off

echo goto is also used to skip a step, example go directly to step-2.
@timeout /t 2 /nobreak>NUL
goto step-2

:step-1
echo hello world
@timeout /t 2 /nobreak>NUL
::goto step-3
goto:eof

:step-2
echo How are you? Oh sorry, I missed Salute.
@timeout /t 2 /nobreak>NUL
::goto step-1
call :step-1

:step-3
echo Show me your code
@timeout /t 2 /nobreak>NUL
::type %~f0 | more

exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your original code, line 4 you have a goto, which is fine

```
@echo off

REM   Process started
goto zeroth
```

so the code goes to "zeroth" as it should. but than at the end of :zeroth you don't have any code to tell the batch file to go anywhere else, so it continues to go down. using `goto` is a good way to jump around the batch file. but if you're just going to down the line, IE goto 0, 1, 2, 3... you don't really need a `goto` at all, you could simply remove all of the gotos and the code will run just fine.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM   Process started
goto zeroth

:zeroth
cls
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Waiting
echo  * op2                                     Waiting
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
echo.
TIMEOUT>NUL /T 1
::zeroth done, going to next
goto first
:first
cls
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Waiting
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
echo.
TIMEOUT>NUL /T 1
:: first done, going to next
:second
cls
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Done
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
echo.

pause
:: Processes all done
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SomethingDark's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32639873/2202732), I changed my code to this:

```
@ECHO OFF

call :1stOpRunning
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
REM   1st op code

call :2ndOpRunning
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
REM   2nd op code

call :3rdOpRunning
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
REM   3rd op code

call :4thOpRunning
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
REM   4th op code

call :allDone

exit /b

:1stOpRunning
cls
echo.
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Waiting
echo  * op2                                     Waiting
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
cls
echo.
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Processing
echo  * op2                                     Waiting
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
goto :eof

:2ndOpRunning
cls
echo.
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Processing
echo  * op3                                     Waiting
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
goto :eof

:3rdOpRunning
cls
echo.
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Done
echo  * op3                                     Processing
echo  * op4                                     Waiting
echo ====================================================
goto :eof

:4thOpRunning
cls
echo.
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Done
echo  * op3                                     Done
echo  * op4                                     Processing
echo ====================================================
goto :eof

:allDone
cls
echo.
echo    Operation                               Status
echo ====================================================
echo  * op1                                     Done
echo  * op2                                     Done
echo  * op3                                     Done
echo  * op4                                     Done
echo ====================================================
echo.

echo    Press any key to continue . . .
timeout /t 5 > NUL
exit
```